# Running Clogin through PHP exec()

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a PHP page that I can go to in order to get information from cisco switches we have. My only current option for reading data from them is to use rancid's clogin.

When I run:

```
sudo -u www-data /usr/lib/rancid/bin/clogin -f /home/www-data/.cloginrc -c 'show run int fa 0/1' as-switch-123 2>&1
```

it runs and returns the information about port 0/1.

However when I run the following:

```
<?php

    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);


    $mainCommand = "/usr/lib/rancid/bin/clogin -f /home/www-data/.cloginrc -c 'show run int fa 0/1' as-switch-123 2>&1";


    $outputArray = array();
    echo exec($mainCommand,$outputArray,$returnCode);
    echo '<br /><br />';
    var_dump($outputArray);
    echo '<br /><br />';
    var_dump($returnCode);

?>
```

I get the return from $outputArray shown below:

```
array(5) { 
    [0]=> string(16) "no such variable" 
    [1]=> string(31) " (read trace on "env(HOME)")" 
    [2]=> string(23) " invoked from within" 
    [3]=> string(40) ""set password_file $env(HOME)/.cloginrc"" 
    [4]=> string(47) " (file "/usr/lib/rancid/bin/clogin" line 66)"
}
```

Does anyone know why its not giving me the output the same as when you run it from sudo?

Answer (score 0):

The error you got tells me that there was a problem with an environment variable, and the only environment variable in the line of code it was trying to process is $HOME.

I expect you would be able to replcate this using:

```
sudo -u www-data "HOME= ; /usr/lib/rancid/bin/clogin -f /home/www-data/.cloginrc -c 'show run int fa 0/1' as-switch-123 2>&1"
```

Similarly setting a value inside the command executed in PHP should solve the problem.

```
$mainCommand = "HOME=/home/www-data && /usr/lib/rancid/bin/clogin -f /home/www-data/.cloginrc -c 'show run int fa 0/1' as-switch-123 2>&1";
```

Comment: The new $mainCommand had the same error as before.

Also when running the sudo command provided it still worked but gave me the following sudo error first:

usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
usage: sudo -l [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user] [-u user] [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user] [VAR=value]
            [-i|-s] [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user] file ...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to symcbean I looked in /usr/lib/rancid/bin/clogin and on line 66 it had the following:

set password_file $env(HOME)/.cloginrc

-f /home/www-data/.cloginrc was not overriding the above and I could not get $env(HOME) set right.

For a quick and probably sloppy fix I manually set line 66 to read set password_file /home/www-data/.cloginrc and it worked.